# Inference with Gaussian Random Variable

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, random-variable, inference

Let $X = N(0,\frac{1}{\alpha})$, $Y = 2X + 8 + N_{y}$, and $N_{y}$ be a noise $N_{y} = N(0,1)$.  Then, $P(y|x)  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}exp\{ -\frac{1}{2}(y - 2x - 8)^{2} \}$
and $P(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}}exp\{-\frac{\alpha x^{2}}{2}\} $.

The mean vector is:

$$\mathbf{\mu} =  \left( \begin{array}{c}
\mu_{x}\\
\mu_{y}\end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{c}
0\\
8\end{array} \right).$$

The question is how to calculate the variance of Y.

I know that the correct answer is

$$\frac{4}{\alpha} + 1, $$

but don't know how to get from 
$$var(Y) = E[(Y-\mu_{y})^{2}] = E[(2X+N_{y})^{2}] $$

to

$$\frac{4}{\alpha} + 1. $$

Can anybody help?
UPDATE:
Thank you All for answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The law of iterated expectations can help here.  We have:

$$Var[Y]=E(Var[Y|X])+Var[E(Y|X)]$$

Now conditional on $X$ the expected value of $Y$ is $2X+8$, and its variance is $1$.  So we have:

$$Var[Y]=E(1)+Var[2X+8]=1+4 Var[X]=1+\frac{4}{\alpha}$$

Comment: (+1) not so straightforward algebra, nice alternative solution.

Answer (score 6):

Solution to this homework is straightforward application of **simple** algebra and independence of $X$ and $N_y$: $\mathbb{E} (2 X + N_y)^2 = 4 \mathbb{E} X^2 + 4 \mathbb{E} X \mathbb{E} N_y + \mathbb{E} N_y^2 = 4 Var X + 0 + Var N_y = \frac{4}{\alpha} + 1$.

Comment: Thanks for a swift answer, not a homework though. Would have tagged it as such if it really was.